# “checked” do “ion-radio” não funciona

Tags: android, ionic, typescript, angular

```
<ion-list radio-group style="margin-bottom:10px;" [(ngModel)]="orcamento.tipo" name="tipo" #tipo="ngModel">

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Consumidor</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="consumidor" checked="true"></ion-radio>

    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Revenda</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="revenda"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

Queria que a primeira opção desses radio inputs viesse selecionada como padrão, mas no template ele fica assim:

[image: Imagem]

Porque a opção não está vindo selecionada?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yk62zsxv/55/

Comment: Só aproveitando o seu jsfiddle, quando eu instalei o ionic, nao veio com aquele arquivo app.js (que em todos os tutoriais se usa ele), e em nenhum arquivo a programação veio nesse "modelo": (angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']).controlle). Tem a ver com a versão do ionic?

Comment: Sim. Ele e utilizado para ter acesso aos componentes no ionic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perceba que dentro do seu ion-list possui um ngModel que é onde será armazenado o valor da opção selecionada, cada ion-radio possuí um value, para você inicializar o component com um selecionado, basta inicializar a variável "orcamento.tipo" com o value do ion-radio que você deseja que comece selecionado, exemplo:

-- Seu component.ts --

```
orcamento.tipo = 'consumidor';
```

Adicionando este código em seu constructor ou no seu onInit do component já deve vir selecionado, não precisando do checked no html, pois será feito o bind do valor do ngModel do radio selecionado.

**UPDATE**

-- Seu component.ts --

```
orcamento = { tipo: 'consumidor', ... seus outros atributos de orcamento };
```

O erro aconteceu pois seu orcamento é um objeto, veja onde você o inicializa e no campo tipo defina com o value do ion-radio desejado.

Na verdade quando você seleciona um ion-radio ele faz isso por trás, adiciona o value do ion-radio no ngModel, então se você inicializar o valor dele com um selecionado, ele vai buscar dentro do ion-list qual ion-radio tem o value informado e vai o selecionar.

Comment: Apareceu um erro: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'tipo' of undefined

Comment: Corrigi a resposta.

Comment: Agora sim! Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa desse true, é só passar o "checked"

```
<ion-radio value="consumidor" checked></ion-radio>
```

Caso não de  certo, tente

```
<ion-radio value="orderBy1" [checked]="orderBy1">
```

Comment: Apenas com o checked também não foi :/
Também tentei com [checked]="consumidor" e não apareceu nada...